# Modifying RX Computational Expression Builder to hold previous values

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I'm using a slightly modified version of the RX builder presented here:

http://mnajder.blogspot.com/2011/09/when-reactive-framework-meets-f-30.html

Rather than taking `IObservable<'T>` directly my computational expression has a type of:

```
type MyType<'a,'b> = MyType of (IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'b>)

let extract (MyType t) = t
```

Combinators then take on the form:

```
let where (f: 'b -> bool) (m:MyType<_,'b>) = MyType(fun input -> (extract m input).Where(f))
```

Within the expression itself, I often need to reference back to previous values that have been fed into the stream.  In order to do so, I've defined a `MyType` which maintains a rolling immutable list of the `n` most recent values.

```
let history n = 
    MyType(fun input ->
        Observable.Create(fun (o:IObserver<_>) ->
            let buffer = new History<_>(n)
            o.OnNext(HistoryReadOnly(buffer))
            input.Subscribe(buffer.Push, o.OnError, o.OnCompleted)
        )
    )
```

With this, I can now do something like:

```
let f = obs {
    let! history = history 20
    // Run some other types, and possibly do something with history
}
```

I am finding that I am using this history quite frequently, ideally I would want to have this embedded directly into `IObservable<'a>`.  Obviously I can't do that.  So my question is, what is a reasonable way to introduce this concept of history that I have here.  Should I be extending `IObservable<'T>` (not sure how to do that), wrapping the `IObservable<'T>`?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Edit: Added full example code.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Reactive.Subjects
open System.Reactive.Linq

// Container function
type MyType<'a,'b> = MyType of (IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'b>)
let extract (MyType t) = t

// Mini Builder
let internal mbind (myTypeB:MyType<'a,'b>) (f:'b -> MyType<'a,'c>) = 
    MyType(fun input ->
        let obsB = extract myTypeB input
        let myTypeC= fun resB -> extract (f resB) input
        obsB.SelectMany(myTypeC)
    )

type MyTypeBuilder() = 
    member x.Bind (m,f) = mbind m f
    member x.Combine (a,b) = MyType(fun input -> (extract a input).Concat(extract b input))
    member x.Yield (r) = MyType(fun input -> Observable.Return(r))
    member x.YieldFrom (m:MyType<_,_>) = m
    member x.Zero() = MyType(fun input -> Observable.Empty())
    member x.Delay(f:unit -> MyType<'a,'b>) = f() 

let mtypeBuilder = new MyTypeBuilder()

// Combinators
let simplehistory = 
    MyType(fun input ->
        Observable.Create(fun (o:IObserver<_>) ->
            let buffer = new List<_>()
            o.OnNext(buffer)
            input.Subscribe(buffer.Add, o.OnError, o.OnCompleted)
        )
    )

let where (f: 'b -> bool) m = MyType(fun input -> (extract m input).Where(f))
let take (n:int) m = MyType(fun input -> (extract m input).Take(n))
let buffer m = MyType(fun input -> (extract m input).Buffer(1))
let stream = MyType(id)

// Example
let myTypeResult (t:MyType<'a,'b>) (input:'a[]) = (extract t (input.ToObservable().Publish().RefCount())).ToArray().Single()

let dat = [|1 .. 20|]

let example = mtypeBuilder {
    let! history = simplehistory
    let! someEven = stream |> where(fun v -> v % 2 = 0) // Foreach Even
    let! firstValAfterPrevMatch = stream |> take 1 // Potentially where a buffer operation would run, all values here are after i.e. we cant get values before last match
    let! odd = stream |> where(fun v -> v % 2 = 1) |> take 2 // Take 2 odds that follow it
    yield (history.[history.Count - 1], history.[0], someEven,firstValAfterPrevMatch, odd) // Return the last visited item in our stream, the very first item, an even, the first value after the even and an odd
}

let result = myTypeResult example dat

val result : (int * int * int * int * int) [] =
  [|(5, 1, 2, 3, 5); (7, 1, 2, 3, 7); (7, 1, 4, 5, 7); (9, 1, 4, 5, 9);
    (9, 1, 6, 7, 9); (11, 1, 6, 7, 11); (11, 1, 8, 9, 11); (13, 1, 8, 9, 13);
    (13, 1, 10, 11, 13); (15, 1, 10, 11, 15); (15, 1, 12, 13, 15);
    (17, 1, 12, 13, 17); (17, 1, 14, 15, 17); (19, 1, 14, 15, 19);
    (19, 1, 16, 17, 19)|]
```

Comment: Given you added the bounty after some good answers below, can you provide some specific examples where those options don't give you what you need?

Comment: @DaxFohl Added a fully working example.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [standard Rx workflow builder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/05/30/nice-f-syntax-for-rx-reactive-extensions.aspx), you can create a function `history` that handles your example use case:

```
let history (io:IObservable<_>) = 
  io.Scan(new List<_>(), (fun l t -> l.Add t; l)).Distinct()

let io = new Subject<int>()
let newio = rx { let! history = history io
                 let! even = io.Where(fun v -> v % 2 = 0)
                 let! next = io.Take 1
                 let! odd = io.Where(fun v -> v % 2 = 1).Take 2
                 yield (history.Last(), history.[0], even, next, odd) }

newio.Subscribe(printfn "%O") |> ignore

for i = 1 to 20 do
  io.OnNext i
```

Extending that to provide history length limits should be trivial.  Was there a specific reason you need to define your own type/builder, or was doing that just a means to attain something like this?

Here's an example with combinators.  You just have to define the observable outside the `rx` block.  You could get `history` to work differently with immutable histories rather than a persistent list, so whatever fits your needs.

```
let history (io:IObservable<_>) = 
  io.Scan(new List<_>(), (fun l t -> l.Add t; l))

let newest (hist:'a List) = hist.Last()
let extract (ioHist:'a List IObservable) = ioHist.Select newest
let take (i:int) (ioHist: 'a List IObservable) = ioHist.Take i
let where (f: 'a -> bool) (ioHist: 'a List IObservable) = ioHist.Where(fun hist -> f(newest hist))

let io = new Subject<int>()
let history1 = history io
let newio =
 rx { let! hist = history1.Distinct()
      let! even = extract (history1 |> where (fun v -> v % 2 = 0))
      let! next = extract (history1 |> take 1)
      let! odd = extract (history1 |> where (fun v -> v % 2 = 1) |> take 2)
      yield (hist.Last(), hist.[0], even, next, odd) }
```

Comment: The encapsulating type exists because it allows for adding a new backing implementation without breaking things down the road.  Currently it is `IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'b>`, perhaps this becomes `IHistoryObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'b>`.  This could change.  What I am looking for here is a means to make history part of the observable itself i.e. I want history accessible to all combinators from within the combinator.  This would mean not having to implicitly define the history within the expression but be able to access it if required. Looking for a clean way to do that.

Comment: @Dave but `history` function doesn't need to be used within an expression at all.  You can nakedly call `let obsWithHistory = history obs`, and that will create an observable that reports full history of `obs` each time `obs` has an event.

Comment: @Dave   I don't *particularly* care for the above because `List` is a single mutable variable that just gets updated.  If you look at my original C# solution (pre-edit) you can see there are some different options, both immutable: you can make it so that `obsWithHistory` reports the full history since its instantiation, or so that just reports the history to each observer since that particular observer has been listening.  These make expressions *slightly* more cumbersome because each variable is now an array, but I think it gives you more flexibility.  Again, not *quite* sure what you need.

Comment: If you define a combinator (based on my example).  You could have something like `MyType(input -> (extract m input)....do something)`.  Would like to be able to access history from `input`.  Basically modify/extend/wrap do something with observable.

Comment: @Dave added combinators

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid having to use extract within the builder i.e. have the builder extract the result, trying to make expressions as least cumbersome as possible.

Comment: @Dave I think I finally see where you're going now.  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Difficult to explain but yes, glad you see what I am talking about now.

Comment: Yes, we ended up having to implement our own Observable which maintained an internal history.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Observable.Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.buffer%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to do this already. 
Sorry for the C# my F# hat is not thinking today.

```
IObservable<int> source = ...
IOBservable<IList<int>> buffered = source.Buffer(5,1)
```

will create you a stream of lists.

Or try to use buffer in LINQ which is more like F# query expressions

```
Console.WriteLine ("START");
var source = new List<int> () { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.ToObservable ();

// LINQ C#'s Monad sugar
var r = 
        from buffer in source.Buffer (3, 1)
        from x in buffer
        from y in buffer
        select new { x,y};


r.Subscribe (o=>Console.WriteLine (o.x + " " + o.y));
Console.WriteLine ("END");
```

Note `from` in LINQ is exactly/almost the same as `let!` in an f# query expression. The result is below. Also note how I am using `buffer` later in the `expression` just like you could in an f# query expression.

```
START
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 2
3 3
3 4
4 2
4 3
4 4
3 3
3 4
3 5
4 3
4 4
4 5
5 3
5 4
5 5
4 4
4 5
5 4
5 5
5 5
END
```

Comment: You cannot.  Observable will buffer for N elements, N time or when triggered to stop by another stream, it will match those conditions and return what has come through the stream.  History in this case will match and allow the expression to continue forward.  After this point it will just log incoming values in a mutable, it will always have the previous N values.  The two are very different.  What I am looking for is for a way to bake this history concept inside of my structure.  i.e. in MyType I want to access history from IObservable<'a> even if that means making it a new type.

Comment: With buffer you always have the previous N samples.  You also have the current sample. I don't understand why you can't build on this.

Comment: With buffer I also need to know when to stop buffering.  With history I do not, history also manages keeping the most recent elements.

Comment: The whole point of buffering is to keep the most recent N elements. You are not making sense here. You don't need to know when to stop buffering. It is an RX combinator. It finishes when the inputs stream completes or on error.

Comment: I think you are getting confused and think that buffer just buffers N elements and then completes. This is not the case.

Comment: When you invoke the computational expression via let!, selectmany is invoked.  The expression continues and the next combinator will ONLY receive values being pushed through since the last matching expression.  At this point how is Buffer going to help?

Comment: That is exactly how buffer works. Buffer could be implemented by SelectMany easily. For every sample that the buffer is empty return an empty list. For the sample when the buffer is full you return a list with a single element where the element is the full buffer or copy thereof. SelectMany concats the stream stripping the empties out and only leaving the samples with the full buffer.

Comment: @Dave I agree with this answer.  Using `Buffer` is far more flexible than building your own expression builder, because it lets you choose *which* observable to maintain history, independent of which expression builder you use.  You can maintain history on the input observable, on the result observable, some intermediate observable, whatever.  It just converts your `Observable<T>` into an `Observable<List<T>>` that presents full history with each new reading.  What else would you want?  With a custom expression builder, you're locked in for the whole block.

Comment: @Dax I understand what the buffer is.  The proposed solution unfortunately doesn't demonstrate how it integrates with the RX builder.

Comment: @Dave the LINQ example he gave would be equivalent to how you'd use the expression builder.  I think you need to give a very explicit example of a use case you're envisioning where this would not work. If `Buffer` doesn't solve your problem I'd love to write something that does, but I don't see the use case you need that `Buffer` doesn't solve.  I'm sure I'm not the only one.  Give us a *specific* case you're envisioning where `Buffer` won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my F# is extremely rusty, but perhaps you are looking for the `Scan` operator. It will push values to an accumulator as the source produces them and then you can use this accumulator to produce the next value for your projection.

Here (in C#, apologies) we take a sequence of [0..10] which produces these value 100ms apart, and we return a running Sum.

```
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
                       .Take(10);

source.Scan(
    new List<long>(),               //Seed value
    (acc, value)=>                  //Accumulator function
        {
            acc.Add(value);
            return acc;
        }
    )
    .Select(accumate=>accumate.Sum())
```

which produces the values [0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45] 100ms apart.

I would think with this tool you can manage your History of values (by adding them to a history/accumulator) and then using this History in the Select to project the value that is appropriate.